# Improved Euler Method

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, error-handling

So I have this code for improved Euler Method dow below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


int = np.array([50, 256])

yt = lambda x: 2*x**4
f = lambda x,t: 4*y/x

x0 = 1.
xf = 3.

for i in range(len(int)):
    x = np.linspace(x0, xf, int[i]+1)
    h = (xf-x0)/int[i]

    y = np.zeros(int[i]+1)
    y[0] = yt(x0)

    for k in range(1, len(y)):
        fk = f(x[k-1], y[k-1])
        fkh = f(x[k], y[k-1]+h* f(x[k-1], y[k-1]))
        y[k] = y[k-1] + (h/2.)*(fk+fkh)

        abserr = np.abs(yt(x) - y)

        plt.semilogy(x,abserr,'*')
        plt.show()
```

However, when I run it it gives me this error which I have no idea how to fix. I have searched online and I've seen people vectorize it but I haven't gotten that to work. Any advice or solution would be greatly appreciated

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "noah.py", line 23, in <module>
    y[k] = y[k-1] + (h/2.)*(fk+fkh)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the definition of the lambda function f. It should be

```
f = lambda x,y: 4*y/x
```

Because of the typo, the function was returning an array of length 51 and 257, which is from the definition of x. Another issue I found, it would be better programming practice to change the variable "int" to something like "int_1." This is because int is part of the Python language.